# How do I use ctrl+k as a shortcut in VS Code, instead as the start of a chord?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use ctrl+hjkl to move between splits in VSCode, but ctrl+k waits for a second key.

edit: I'm currently using:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+h ctrl+h", "command": "workbench.action.navigateLeft"},
{ "key": "ctrl+l ctrl+l", "command": "workbench.action.navigateRight"},
{ "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+k", "command": "workbench.action.navigateUp"},
{ "key": "ctrl+j ctrl+j", "command": "workbench.action.navigateDown"},
```

Comment: Did you try removing all keybidings that use it as chord?

Comment: Consider picking a different modifier (`alt`). VSC uses `ctrl+k` as the first part of a huge amount of chords, removing them all doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CherryDT I didn't because there's so many, I guess I could find+replace all or something in keybindings.json